# Nonrecusrsive Scalar projection

Tags: prolog

I need to implement nonrecusrsive scalar projection for lists. List is a recursive data structure in Prolog. Is that also possible? I try to implement like:

```
scalar(T,U,S) :- scalar(T,U,S,0).
scalar([X|T],[Y|U],S,M):- repeat,M1 = M + S, S1=X*Y,fail.

repeat.
repeat:-repeat.
```

But it wrong because I not pass M1 S1.

It's so difficult to understand after C coding. Prolog iteration clause is recursive but with "Tail" recursion. It's mean we have right answer on the end of recursion. Recursive clause need to bactrack to up to get the answer.

Nonrecursive method

```
scal(L1,L2,R):- scal(L1,L2,0,R).
scal([A|L1],[B|L2],F,R):- F1 is (F + A*B),scal(L1,L2,F1,R).
scal([],[],F,F).
```

Recursive method

```
scal([],[],0).
scal([A|L1],[B|L2],R) :- scal(L1, L2, R1), R is (R1+A*B).
```

Comment: [scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) has nothing to do with recursion, or iteration. Please specify better your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the scalar projection of vector A onto B given by:

```
s = (A dot B)/|B|
```

Then you could do it this way:

```
scalar(A, B, S) :-
    dot_product(A, B, P),
    magnitude(B, M),
    S is P / M.

dot_product(A, B, P) :-
    maplist(mult, A, B, M),
    sum_list(M, P).               % In SWI prolog, this would be sumlist

magnitude(V, M) :-
    maplist(sq, V, S),            % Or maplist(mult, V, V, S)
    sum_list(S, SumS),
    M is sqrt(SumS).

mult(X, Y, M) :- M is X * Y.
sq(X, S) :- S is X * X.
```

Comment: Consider `... maplist(\X^Y^M^(M is X*Y), A, B, M), ...` and `... maplist(\X^S^(S is X*X)) ...` instead using [library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

Comment: @false ah thanks. I was thinking there was a more compact way to implement the sum/product mechanisms.